# GA4 landing page missing (sub)domain

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to generate a report that shows first-click attribution for an event but the "Landing page + query string" filter is only showing me the end of the URL and skips domain/subdomain entirely, creating confusion. It was previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74146935/adding-domain-name-to-landing-page-dimension-in-ga4) but didn't get any valid answer.
Any idea how to show it? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? This is crucial for multi-site setups and was trivial in UA.

Comment: So far we've found the following:  1) GA4 does have an attribution model comparison tool, which you’ll find it in the “Advertising” section (left sidebar). You can use source / medium as a dimension and compare the different attribution models. You still can’t use the landing page + query string as a second dimension, as it’s session-scoped, so will give irrelevant/wrong results. We’ll try to add a custom, user-scoped landing_page dimension and see.  2) You can create a conversion funnel In the exploration part using the "Free Form" function and "First user source / medium" as the row.